# text foreground ColorAnimation - color is not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to animate color change in a TextBlock using code behind to change the text from black to red but it isn't changing from black to red, nor is it producing a compile time or run time error.

This is how my code looks. I expect it to be changing to red on line 21 where I have the comment. It is staying black.

```cs
        TextBlock tb2= new TextBlock();
        tb2.Inlines.Add("An example on ");
        ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames colorAnimation = new 
        ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        Color redColor = new Color();
        SolidColorBrush animatedBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        animatedBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0); //start black

        tb2.Foreground = animatedBrush;
        this.RegisterName(
          "AnimatedBrush", animatedBrush);

        colorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);

        redColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);//set red color

        colorAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(
                new LinearColorKeyFrame(
                    redColor, // Target value (KeyValue)
                    KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)))); 
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(animatedBrush, "AnimatedBrush");//change to new color
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
            colorAnimation, new 
        PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
        Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myStoryboard.Children.Add(colorAnimation);
        Button butonier = new Button();
        butonier.Content = "klikaj";
        this.RegisterName("butonier", butonier);
        sPanel.Children.Add(butonier);

        butonier.Click += delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myStoryboard.Begin(this);
        };

        this.Content = sPanel; //stackpanel
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what color are you trying to change

Comment: What does "not working" mean? are you getting an error or what is happening?

Comment: Nothing happens. Color is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with this line:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(animatedBrush, "AnimatedBrush");
```

it should be:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(colorAnimation, "AnimatedBrush");
```

You also haven't added your text block to the stack panel. This can go next to where you add the button.

```
sPanel.Children.Add(tb2);
```

If that doesn't get you what you need please edit your question with more info.